# Массив в массиве: выбрать только 1 значение ['status'] = 0

Tags: php

Всем привет. Есть массив в массиве `$myMessage['viewed']` в нем у элементов ключ `['status']`, который меня и интересует. Все работает ок, только если у меня например 3 сообщения со `['status'] == 0` мне выдает NEW NEW NEW

Задача у каждого `item` проверить статус, и если хотя бы у одного из них он равен нулю, то надо вывести один NEW. Как это можно реализовать без вмешательства в SQL?

```
<?php foreach ($myMessage['viewed'] as $item) { ?>
     <?php if( $item['status'] == 0) { ?>
           <?php $checkByStatus = true; ?>
           <?php if( $checkByStatus == true) { ?>
                 chek = <?php echo $checkByStatus; ?>
                 <span style="color: red;">NEW</span>
           <?php }?>
     <?php } ?>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Вывод NEW у вас должен находиться после цикла, до цикла сделайте переменную $hasNewMessage = false; и меняйте её значение на true в внутри if.

Comment: И делайте бряк внутри if т.к. Если у вас хотя бы один раз выполнилось условие вам нужно вывести NEW и для этого вам не нужно бежать по остальным n записям.

Comment: @fens Первый вариант не помог. Решилось через break.

Comment: Первый вариант это как написать читаемый код, поиск что у вас внутри if происходит установка переменной в true которая зачем то проверяется на истинность...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так и прервите цикл с помощью break после первого же вывода NEW.

Comment: Все гениальное просто. Спасибо.